# Which music plays in Bleach episode 283 at 10:33 mins?

Tags: music, bleach

I was searching the music which plays in *Bleach* episode 283 at 10:33 but couldn't find anywhere.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Could you describe the scene where this happens, and also how the music sounds like? You can always [edit] your post to improve it. It would help the answerers with more detailed info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Soundscape to Ardor](https://youtu.be/Q2aM5btBLVU), which is in [Bleach OST 3](https://vgmdb.net/album/22886), if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

Morning Remembrance, from Bleach OST. If I got the correct song. It happens during the fight of Stark and Kyoraku, right? Link down there

[Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZl5rEKCk9g)